# Need To Find My Own Process ID In VB6

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am changing the architecture of a VB 6 scheduling application from serial execution architecture to parallel execution and I need to do this with as little code changes as possible.  Basically, the first instance of the .exe will start a defined amount of additional instances.

One of the changes required is to update the job table with the PID of the instance that is executing the job.  I have searched but I have not been able to find a way to get this when multiple instances of the same .exe may be running.

How can I get the process ID of the current process?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's normally a good idea to add an actual answerable question to your post. Note that [StackOverflow already adds a signature for you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) so you shouldn't add one manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it the same way a program in any other language would do it: Call [`GetCurrentProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885614.aspx).

Comment: Oops...I thought that wouldn't work correctly with multiple .exes running.  My bad :)

Answer (score 12):

Put in this into your code:

```
Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetCurrentProcessId" () As Long
```